# Facebook connect android to get my email address?

Tags: android, facebook

How to get my email-address and facebook id using facebook connect in android?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1):

> You need the email permission to read the users email adress. That
>   will add a email tag in your json-response from [uid] or me requests.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.LoginButton;

public class FacebookIntegrationActivity extends Activity 
{
    public static final String APP_ID = "166597773469222";     // TestFBIntegration App 
    private Facebook mFacebook;
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    private LoginButton mLoginButton;
    private TextView mText;
    private Button buttonLoad = null,buttonBlackAndWhite=null;
    private String uniq_id,first_name,last_name,avatar,user_name,emailaddress;

    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS =
            new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access","user_photos","user_likes","friends_photos","friends_likes","email"};

    private ImageView imageViewFacebook = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initControls();
    }


    private void initControls()
    {
        try
        {
            if (APP_ID == null) 
            {
                Util.showAlert(this, "Warning", "Facebook Applicaton ID must be " +
                        "specified before running this example");
            }

             mLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login);
             mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

             mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
             mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

             SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, this);
             SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());
             SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new SampleLogoutListener());
             mLoginButton.init(this, mFacebook,PERMISSIONS);

             buttonLoad = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLoad);
             buttonLoad.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     public class SampleAuthListener implements AuthListener 
     {
            public void onAuthSucceed() 
            {
                mText.setText("You have logged in! ");
                mAsyncRunner.request("me&fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,picture", new SampleRequestListenerForUniqueId());
                Log.i("------------- Get Access Tokens","=============== :: "+mFacebook.getAccessToken());
            }
            public void onAuthFail(String error) {
                mText.setText("Login Failed: " + error);
            }
      }

      public class SampleLogoutListener implements LogoutListener 
      {
            public void onLogoutBegin() 
            {
                mText.setText("Logging out...");
            }

            public void onLogoutFinish() 
            {
                mText.setText("You have logged out! ");
            }
        }


        public class SampleRequestListenerForUniqueId extends BaseRequestListener 
        {
            public void onComplete(final String response,Object state) 
            {
                try 
                {
                     JSONObject dataObject = Util.parseJson(response);
                     uniq_id = dataObject.getString("id");
                     user_name = dataObject.getString("name");
                     first_name = dataObject.getString("first_name");
                     last_name = dataObject.getString("last_name");
                     emailaddress = dataObject.getString("email");
                     avatar = dataObject.getString("picture");
                } 
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
                } 
                catch (FacebookError e) 
                {
                    Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
}
```

### Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <com.facebook.android.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:src="@drawable/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txt" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textColor="@drawable/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load Photo Albums" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFacebook"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="300dip"
        android:src="@drawable/login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBlackAndWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Black and White"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Here, you are getting only id,name,first_name,last_name,picture. what about email address?

Comment: i didnt get any email string from JSONObject (dataObject). i got only id, name,first_name,last_name and username.   picture(not there)

Comment: i think your email id is not public . You have to make it public from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if I'm not mistaken this information could be obtained from [Graph API](http://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) that Facebook offers. You will need to log in, in order to access it.

Answer (score 0):

LoginButton is a Facebook SDK native object (com.facebook.widget.LoginButton) implemented in my view.

**View Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/login_options"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
        </com.facebook.widget.LoginButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code :**

```
RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_options, container, false);    

LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);

authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
```